# Is it standard way to use javaargs instead of overloading in Java?

Tags: java, overloading

Is it a standard way to code or any other alternatives are there? I thinking this a while about the code that I've written. Finally gave up and thought to check with you guys.

Here is the scenario I had.

```
private String functionNameXYZ(String a,String b) {
   //Logic goes here
}
private String functionNameXYZ(String a,String b,String c) {
   //Same logic goes here , Nothing much difference because of String c
}
```

So I tho
ught to skip two functions for same purpose and I created a single function as below.

```
private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b,String... c){
   return performlogic(a,b,(c.lenght!=0)? c[0]:null);
}
private String performlogic(String a,String b, String c) {
   //logic , return "string"
}
```

Which is standard way of coding? Was it to seperate logic into new method instead of repeating[Second case] or Was it other way? Kindly suggest if you find any better ways?

Comment: Use varargs, if you are expecting an arbitrary amount of arguments (like in `String.format`), but use overloading, if you are expecting a constant and specific order of the arguments. Plus: You can even specify different types using overloading; this is not easily possible with varargs.

Comment: The thing most do, is overload. The overload suggests different handling, or logic, though. That's the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your only two valid options are two `String` arguments and three `String` arguments, using varargs is a tad overkill, and worse - it's confusing, as it implies that you could also pass five or ten or a gazillion arguments. Instead, you could do something much simpler:

```
private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b) {
   functionNameXYZ(a, b, null);
}

private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b, String c) {
   // One place for the logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, Followed this way :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first scenario is fine, except you want to maybe take any large bulk of common code in the functions and put it in a separate function (or more easily, have the function with less params call the one with more).

The overloading is fine, but rewriting the same code both places is not good practice.

Also, since Java doesn't have default parameters, I'm not too keen on having a *public* method's argument that is *nullable*, even if noted on the JavaDocs. Overloading is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to ask yourself a question: what input is legal?

If your program should handle 2...n arguments, then absolutely go with the varargs. However if the legal input to your function is either exactly 2 or 3 arguments, then you should use the pattern:

```
private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b) {
   // logic of function
}

private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b, String c) {
   // place the logic for handling 'c' input then call
   functionNameXYZ(a, b);
}
```

Alternatively, as the other poster mentioned:

```
private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b) {
   functionNameXYZ(a, b, null);
}

private String functionNameXYZ(String a, String b, String c) {
   // One place for the logic
}
```

Personally, I prefer the first approach as it clearly separates the logic used to handle the 'c' parameter and the others. This is commonly used when you can seperate that logic, e.g. in constructors. However, when the logic can't easily be untangled go for the second approach.